# Send POST request with Pillow image

Tags: python, request, python-imaging-library, pymongo

I get an image from pymongo like this:

```
    def get_my_photo(self, user_id):
        res = self.db.find_one({'user_id': user_id})
        image_data = BytesIO(res['photo'])
        image = Image.open(image_data)
        image_data = BytesIO()
        image.save(image_data, "JPEG")
        image_data.seek(0)
        return image_data
```

Then i try send POST request with image_data:

```
request = requests.post(url, files={'photo': image})
```

But headers is:
`'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=windows-1251'`.
And there is no photo uploading. 
How correctly send Pillow image with a request? Thanks.

Edit: find the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48120516/7732331)

Comment: Also, when I try to save an image from pymongo locally, it works fine.

Comment: have you tried setting the content type of your post request manually using `requests.post(..., headers={'Content-type': XXX})`?

Comment: @mommermi When I try ```requests.post(request['response']['upload_url'], files={'photo': image}, headers={'Content-type': 'image/png'})```, it return ```'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=windows-1251'```